# React Hook Form: isDirty not working on load

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I'm using `react-hook-form` to control and validate a form with one required input.

```
const {control, handleSubmit, formState, reset} = useForm({
  mode: 'onChange',
});
const {isDirty, isValid, errors} = formState;
```

To disable the submit button:

```
disabled={!isDirty || !isValid}
```

The issue is that initially, the submit button is not disabled even if the input is empty.

Comment: How does the input look like and how is it connected to the form? If I connect a plain `<input />` using `register` it works fine in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-mayer-9itlk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Also what are the values of `isDirty` and `isValid` if you log them in render initially?

Comment: Are you maybe setting the values initially through `control.setValue` or maybe you're using `reset` on component mount? It seems to me that the problem is that your `isDirty` variable is initially set to `true`, whereas by default its value is `false`. However, its value can change if you deliberately use `setValue` or `reset`

Comment: I'm wrapping the input with a ``Controller``. ``isDirty`` is ``false`` at first, but the screen is rerendering once switching the first to ``true``. Trying to investigate this.

Comment: @trixn @Kapobajza is there something in particular that makes the useForm change ``isDirty`` on load?

Comment: @MajedBadawi Please provide the relevant code for a minimal example that shows the described behaviour. The code you provided is lacking the important parts to debug that.

Comment: trixn and Kapobajza thanks for the help, problem resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that I was not passing the `defaultValues` of the form elements.
[image]